# Running multiple Numba (Python)

Tags: python, input, parallel-processing, instance, numba

Anyone has an idea on how to run multiple .py files with the jit decorator? i.e. call the function with numba (also cache == True), but with different input values.

Is it possible to use YAWL (Yet Another Workload)?

Many thanks !